# R: Plot means of two separate columns by factor

Tags: r

I have a data set like the following:

```
structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("action", "observation"), class = "factor"), 
    mag1 = structure(c(0.33, 0.83, 0.75, 0.65, 0.75, 0.67, 0.31, 
    0.73, 0.65, 0.73), label = c(mag1 = "mean accuracy Q1 pre-test"), class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), mag2 = structure(c(0.75, 0.9, 0.88, 0.65, 0.69, 
    0.69, 0.54, 0.46, 0.46, 0.6), label = c(mag2 = "mean accuracy Q1 post-test"), class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric"))), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I want to make a line plot with error bar to show the means of column "mag1" and "mag2" so that y is their mean values and x is the column name, which looks like the following:

[image]

How can I do this?

I have tried ggplot2 and qplot but the plot I got is mag1 on the x axis and mag2 on the y axis. I do not want tot rearrange my data to get a column of group, a column indicating mag1&2 and then mean. As a result is there away to plot like the above graph without rearranging data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is called df:

```
head(df)
        group mag1 mag2
1      action 0.33 0.75
2 observation 0.83 0.90
3      action 0.75 0.88
4 observation 0.65 0.65
5      action 0.75 0.69
6 observation 0.67 0.69
```

You need to create a vector for the x group, trace (different line col) and the y value. I don't know if it counts as rearranging your matrix.. Also, you need to indicate what is the error bar, below it plots the 95% CI of the mean in each group:

```
library(sciplot)
X = rep(c("mag1","mag2"),each=nrow(df))
Y =  c(df$mag1,df$mag2)
grp = rep(df$group,2)
lineplot.CI(x.factor=X,group = grp,response =Y,
ylab="mean accuracy Q1 pre-test",xlab="")
```

Or simply:

```
lineplot.CI(x.factor=rep(c("mag1","mag2"),each=nrow(df)),
group = rep(a$group,2),response = c(df$mag1,df$mag2),
ylab="mean accuracy Q1 pre-test",xlab="")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` which contains `ggplot`, you can do:

```
dat %>% 
gather(mag, vals, -group) %>% 
group_by(group, mag) %>% 
summarise(mean_vals = mean(vals), sd_vals = sd(vals)) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = mag, y = mean_vals, group = group, fill = group, color = group)) + geom_line(stat = "identity") + 
geom_point(stat = "identity")+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_vals - sd_vals, ymax = mean_vals + sd_vals), width = 0.05)
```

This results in a graph that looks like:

[image]